# A formula to calculate the partial volume of a capsule or tank?

Tags: geometry, closed-form, volume

We are trying to ascertain the correct formula discussed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1376569/).

The volume formula for a *[capsule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsule_(geometry))* (a cylinder with a *hemisphere* at both ends) is,

$$V_c = \pi r^2 H + \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3\tag1$$

while that of a *tank* (a cylinder with a *hemi-oblate spheroid* at both ends) is,

$$V_t = \pi r^2 H + \frac{4}{3}\pi c r^2\tag2$$

with the capsule being the special case $c = r$.

For example, in this [tank volume calculator](http://www.blocklayer.com/TankHorizontalEng.aspx) diagram, with $H = 192$, $c = 18$, $r=36$, (in inches) the total fill volume is

$$V_t = 879444.88\;\text{in}^3 = 3807.12\; \text{US gallons}$$

and easily computed from $(2)$.

> ***Question***: Using the same diagram, what is the volume of water $V_p$ in a *partially* filled tank with water depth $h$?

**P.S.** Using $h=48\;\text{in}$, the website author claims that,

$$V_p = 2710\; \text{US gallons}$$

However, one cannot arrive at this value using the formula given by the author in the linked post so it is either wrong, or has some missing assumptions.

Comment: @marshalcraft: I assume you mean eq $(1)$ in the other post?

Comment: @marshalcraft: Blatter has found the correct formula how to arrive at the value $2710$. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H$ be the height and $R$ be the radius of the cylinder, and assume that the tank is filled up to height $h$, $0\leq h\leq 2R$. In the case of a capsule the volume of fluid consists of a segment of the cylinder and a segment of of a sphere, the latter coming in two separated halves. The volume of a sphere segment is computed exactly by Kepler's formula. One obtains
$$V_{\rm sph}(h)={\pi h^2\over3} (3R-h)\ .\tag{1}$$
The volume of the cylinder segment is $H$ times the area of a circle segment of height $h$. One obtains
$$V_{\rm cyl}(h)=H\left(R^2\left({\pi\over2}+\arcsin{h-R\over R}\right)+(h-R)\sqrt{h(2R-h)}\right)\ .$$
Equivalently,
$$V_{\rm cyl}(h)=H\left(R^2\left(\arccos{R-h\over R}\right)+(h-R)\sqrt{h(2R-h)}\right)\ .$$
When instead of a sphere we have an ellipsoid with semiaxes $R$, $R$, and $C$ then $V_{\rm sph}(h)$ is multiplied by a factor ${C\over R}$, so that $(1)$ has to be replaced by
$$V'_{\rm sph}(h)={\pi C h^2\over3R} (3R-h)\ .$$
*Responding to a comment:* Given $h$, we now have
$$V_{\rm tank}(h)=V_{\rm cyl}(h)+V'_{\rm sph}(h)\ .$$
The expression on the right hand side contains algebraic terms in the variable $h$, as well as an $\arcsin$-term. Therefore it is impossible to express the inverse function $V\mapsto h(V)$ in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: If $H = 192, h = 48, R = 36$ and I assume $C = c = 18$, then I find the volume of water in the partially-filled tank as, $$\begin{aligned}V_p &= V_{\rm cyl} + V_{\rm sph}'\\ &=553627.04+72382.29\\&=626009.33\;\text{in}^3 = \color{blue}{2710}\;\text{US gallons}\end{aligned}$$ the same as in the website. Great! Thanks.

Comment: Now that we have the correct formula, the essence of the other post is given,$$V_p = H\left(R^2\left( \arccos{R - h\over R}\right) + (h - R)\sqrt{h(2R - h)}\right)+{\pi C h^2\over3R} (3R - h)$$ where we know $V_p$, is there a way to isolate the depth $h$ and express it in terms of the other variables?