# How many integer satisfy the following condition?

Tags: number-theory

$\frac{n}{\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor}\in\mathbb{Z}, 0<n<2016$, where $n$ is an integer

Comment: Context please?  The number $2016$ suggests a math contest, potentially even an active one.

Comment: 131 of them according to excel(or a few line of codes if you prefer).

Comment: @frank000 does brute force make you feel any better.

Comment: Obviously all perfect squares

Comment: @marshalcraft It took me about 30 sec to get a reliable answer by code. It would take me much longer than that to get a reliable answer by the kind of approach Kf-Sansoo is using. These days one needs to be fluent in both approaches.

Comment: Oh I know the utility of it, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1376569/find-the-value-of-h-from-a-kepler-type-equation/1381526#1381526 a more accurate gas guage.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**:

Let $ m = \lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor\implies m \leq \sqrt{n} < m+1\implies m^2 \leq n < (m+1)^2$. Let $k = \dfrac{n}{m}\implies n = mk\implies m^2 \leq mk\leq (m+1)^2\implies m \leq k \leq m+2 + \dfrac{1}{m}\implies k = m, m+1, m+2$ since $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

**Case 1:** $k = m \implies n = mk = m^2\implies m = \sqrt{n}=\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor\implies n = 1, 4, 9, ....q^2, q \in \mathbb{N}$

**Case 2:** $k = m+1 \implies n = km = (m+1)m = m^2 +m < 2016$. From this you can solve for $m$ as its a natural number,and then $n$.

**Case 3:** $k = m+2 \implies n = km = (m+2)m = m^2 + 2m< 2016$. And you can solve for $m$, then for $n$.

From these $3$ cases, you can see how many values of $n$ you can have.